# How do I pass in a function to a constructor that will then be set to a variable?

Tags: c++

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to pass a function into a constructor, set that function to a variable, and then call that variable at a later time. (like a callback)

The error I'm getting is that "no matching constructor" since void isn't the callback... but I thought the callback was just a method which returned void?

header file

```cpp
class Cars {
  typedef void *callback();

  public:
  Cars(callback* method);

  private:
  callback* method;
  void trigger();
}
```

class file

```cpp
Cars::Cars(callback method){
  this->method = method;
}

void Cars::trigger() {
  method();
}
```

main file

```
void doSomething() {
  // does something
}

Cars car = Cars(doSomething());
```

Comment: In modern C++ you'd probably want to use a `std::function` rather than a callback function pointer.

Comment: @tadman — `std::function` adds a fair amount of overhead to support argument conversion and return type conversion. If you don’t need those, there’s no need to incur that overhead.

Comment: @PeteBecker Unless you're making millions of calls I doubt you'd notice.

Comment: @tadman — don’t pay for it if you don’t need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

```
typedef void *callback();
```

This declares `callback` to be a function that returns a pointer to `void`.

```
Cars(callback* method);
```

Therefore, the constructor takes a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to void. Your obvious intent is to use a pointer to a function that returns a `void`, instead of a pointer to a `void`. Therefore, the `typedef` should be:

```
typedef void callback();
```

However, some find the end result to be slightly convoluted. It's more clear to use, instead:

```
typedef void (*callback)();

Cars(callback method);
```

This is the same thing, but a little bit clearer. But that's not the only problem, here.

```
void doSomething() {
  // does something
}
```

This declares and defines a function that returns a `void`.

```
Cars car = Cars(doSomething());
```

Given the above definition, in C++ the expression `doSomething()` means, obviously, a call to this function, which produces a `void` result, which is then passed to `Cars` constructor. That, of course, is not what you want to do. Instead, the correct syntax is:

```
Cars car = Cars(doSomething);
```

or

```
Cars car = Cars(&doSomething);
```

whichever you prefer. The name of a declared function, alone, evaluates to a pointer to the function (with or without an explicit `&`).

Comment: Oh wow, that clears up a lot of questions. Thanks! For the "typedef void (*callback)()," why would that achieve the same thing?

Comment: It's not just that, but also the parameter to the constructor is just `callback` and not `callback *`. The combination of the two is logically identical.